# A license catalog with RDF description, exist?

Tags: rdf, semantic-web

Popular [public copyright licenses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_copyright_license) like [GPL3](http://opensource.org/licenses/GPL-3.0), [MIT](http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT), [Apache2](http://opensource.org/licenses/Apache-2.0), [CC-BY-SA3](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/), etc. have official human-readable texts, and, I suppose, in nowadays, have also translations to "machine-readable texts", that are  [REL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rights_Expression_Language) interpretations/translations of the official texts... Each license is a set of clauses that can be described by REL, and this set is my interest.

**There are a "license database" (or catalog or content with semantic markup) with each license translated to REL or RDF?**

---

NOTES

Existing translations and samples. The only that I found was a [CC licenses translated to  CC-REL](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-ccrel/).

"REL is RDF". 
Any REL (*Rights Expression Language*), ex. [CC-REL](https://wiki.creativecommons.org/wiki/CC_REL) or RightsML, can be translated to RDF, so we can suppose that any popular license tranlated to REL, is a RDF descriptor of the license.

"RDF is JSON-LD, RDFa, Microdata", no problem for me, all can be translated to another.

"catalogues". They exist, as [Wikipedia lists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_free_content_licenses), [OKFN lists](http://licenses.opendefinition.org/#all-licenses), [tldrlegal lists](https://tldrlegal.com/),  and others... But no one have a  REL or RDF translation/interpretation.

Comment: I do not think that there is such a catalogue. For non-software works, it is (de facto) either Creative Commons, GFDL or proprietary. For software, there is a [huge list of more or less standardized licenses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/License_proliferation) which differ in subtle ways. While there are a few projects to implement an REL, like RightsML or [ODRL](https://www.w3.org/community/odrl/implementations/), I have seen the URL of a rights statement used (e.g. https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT or http://usefulinc.com/doap/licenses/gpl.

Comment: Cross-post on [opendata.se]: [A license catalog with RDF description, exist?](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/7012/877)

Comment: @unor, This question is at a point of intersection between the two sites, and cross-post is not a matter of consensus, see [1](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141825/205446) and [2](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64073/205446). I am using explicit copy/paste (no hidden intentions) and the recommendation to delete **after test**. The best local for this question is OpenData, but, as you see (!), here I have good answer and ~3*times more pageviews.  Please wait next steps: 1) my accepting of best awnser here, perhaps to Daniel; 2) my delete or edit of OpenData question.

Comment: @unor, ok (!), can you review your downvote/closevote, now that I accepted Daniel's answer and  ["deleted"  the copy/paste cross-post](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/7012/1313)?

Comment: @PeterKrauss: I was not implying anything with the link, other than informing users that this question also exists on [opendata.se]. And the fact that your question got answered here (and that you got more visits here) is not relevant for deciding if it’s on-topic or not: in my opinion, it’s clearly off-topic on Stack Overflow (and I guess on-topic on [opendata.se]).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Doncel et al (http://delicias.dia.fi.upm.es/~vrodriguez/pdf/2014.11.jurix.dataset.pdf) the authors describe a catalog of licenses translated into RDF.

You can find it here: http://rdflicense.linkeddata.es/, along with a link to download it. I have tried and each of the URIs are derreferenceable (although they might take a little to load), pointing you to the original page of the license. The catalog is described using standard models, such as dublin core or  ODRL.

Comment: I will check later in detail, but [rdflicense.linkeddata.es](http://rdflicense.linkeddata.es/) seems perfect, it is what I was looking for (!).

Comment: Ok, I try to use, but [*RDFLicense dataset* project have limitations described here](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/7012/1313)... But it is not your problem ;-) This is a good answer!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I know the person involved in this, and I'm sure he will be more than happy to receive some constructive criticism of his work. I will forward him your comments